# Deleting specific div's with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to spawn different div's and remove them after they do their job. A simple version of my code is:

```js
   function eraseDiv(){
      var c = document.getElementById("cn1");
      c.parentNode.removeChild(child);
   }

function spawnDiv(){
    var x = document.getElementById("test");
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.id = "child";
    d.style.width = "500px";
    d.style.height = "30px";
    var content = "Some text for testing!" + "<a href=\"?\" onclick=eraseDiv(); return false; > Delete</a>";
    d.innerHTML = content;
    if (document.getElementById("cn1").innerHTML.trim() == "")
        document.getElementById("cn1").appendChild(d); 
    else 
        document.getElementById("cn2").appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Spawn" onclick="spawnDiv(); return false;" />
<div id= "test">
<div id= "cn1"></div>
<div id= "cn2"></div>
</div>'
```

The problem is that when the first spawned div is deleted, all div's are deleted. Any help is appreciated on how to fix this.

Comment: [tag:java] tag deleted. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see how your question has anything to do with Java programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```js
function eraseDiv(target){
    var div = target.parentNode;
    var container = div.parentNode;
    container.removeChild(div);
}

function spawnDiv(){
    var x = document.getElementById("test");
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.style.width = "500px";
    d.style.height = "30px";
    var content = "Some text for testing!" + "<button onclick=eraseDiv(this);> Delete</button>";
    d.innerHTML = content;
    if (document.getElementById("cn1").innerHTML.trim() == "")
        document.getElementById("cn1").appendChild(d); 
    else 
        document.getElementById("cn2").appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="submit" onclick="spawnDiv();">Spawn</button>
<div id= "test">
<div id= "cn1"></div>
<div id= "cn2"></div>
</div>
```

First thing, since you're returning false every time you obviously don't want to use the submit functionality of your submit input, so change it to a button instead.

Second thing, remove the ID from the spawned div since you should never have two divs with the same ID.

Third thing (like the first thing) since you're not using the link functionality of the anchor element, you should change it to a button instead (using CSS you can style this like an anchor if you want to).

Fourth thing, inside the delete button, add `this` as a parameter to the eraseDiv function. You can now access the button that was clicked using the function parameter rather than trying to find it by an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to create a id for div like this

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Spawn" onclick="spawnDiv(); return false;" />
    <div id= "test">
    <div id= "cn1"></div>
    <div id= "cn2"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function eraseDiv(j){
              var c = document.getElementById('child'+j);
              c.parentNode.removeChild(c);   
            }
        var i=1;
        function spawnDiv(){
            var x = document.getElementById("test");
            var d = document.createElement("div");

            d.id = "child"+i;
            d.style.width = "500px";
            d.style.height = "30px";
            var content = "Some text for testing!" + "<u ><a  onclick=eraseDiv("+i+++"); > Delete</a></u>";
            d.innerHTML = content;
            if (document.getElementById("cn1").innerHTML.trim() == "")
                document.getElementById("cn1").appendChild(d); 
            else 
                document.getElementById("cn2").appendChild(d);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `+i+++` do?

Comment: It is to increment the div id on every call to spawnDiv. The id is passed to eraseDiv function so that it knows which div to be deleted similar to @James method of passing this .

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest fix to your code without modifying the functionality (and view of the page) of what you did is to replace the `href="?"` with `href="#"`.**

In your original code, when you do something like `<a href="?">link</a>` with the **"?"** as the hyperlink, this actually performs a GET request which will reload the page. This is tricky because it makes it seem like your delete code is removing all the spawned divs from both `cn1` and `cn2` divs.

Changing the `href=?` to `href=#` prevents a GET request from happening. Below is a snippet that directly makes this change that results in the **correct behavior** of your original code (by deleting the spawned element in `cn1`). You will have to further modify your code to make it do what you want.

```js
function eraseDiv(){
  var c = document.getElementById("cn1");
  c.parentNode.removeChild(c);
}

function spawnDiv(){
    var x = document.getElementById("test");
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.id = "child";
    d.style.width = "500px";
    d.style.height = "30px";
    var content = "Some text for testing!" + "<a href=\"#\" onclick=eraseDiv(); return false; > Delete</a>";
    d.innerHTML = content;
    if (document.getElementById("cn1").innerHTML.trim() == "")
        document.getElementById("cn1").appendChild(d); 
    else 
        document.getElementById("cn2").appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Spawn" onclick="spawnDiv(); return false;" />
  <div id= "test">
      <div id= "cn1"></div>
      <div id= "cn2"></div>
  </div>
```